# I can't get the right answer to Project Euler Q8 with Java

Tags: java

There are 2 answers. The first answer is for 4 consecutive numbers and the answer is provided: 5832. The 2nd answer is for 13 consecutive numbers and it's the answer they want me to input. This answer is: 23514624000.

My answer for the 1st questions is: 29760696 which is impossible and way off

```
public class test {

public static void main(String[] args)
{



String big = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"
        + "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843"
        + "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"
        + "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557"
        + "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113"
        + "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749"
        + "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866"
        + "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776"
        + "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"
        + "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397"
        + "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482"
        + "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474"
        + "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881"
        + "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586"
        + "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"
        + "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408"
        + "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188"
        + "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606"
        + "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"
        + "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"
        ;
//System.out.println(big.length());
int product=1;
int newProduct=0;
for(int i=0;i<big.length()-1-4;i++)
{
    product=1;
    for(int j=i+1;j<i+5;j++)
    {

        product=(big.charAt(i)-48)*(big.charAt(j)-48)*product;

    }

    if(product>newProduct)
    {
        newProduct=product;

    }
}


    System.out.println(newProduct);
}
```

My answer for the 2nd question is: 2135048192 and is a lot closer. Why is this the case? My code is as follows. thanks

```
public class test {

public static void main(String[] args)
{



String big = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"
        + "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843"
        + "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"
        + "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557"
        + "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113"
        + "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749"
        + "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866"
        + "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776"
        + "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"
        + "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397"
        + "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482"
        + "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474"
        + "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881"
        + "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586"
        + "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"
        + "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408"
        + "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188"
        + "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606"
        + "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"
        + "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"
        ;
//System.out.println(big.length());
int product=1;
int newProduct=0;
for(int i=0;i<big.length()-1-13;i++)
{
    product=1;
    for(int j=i+1;j<i+14;j++)
    {

        product=(big.charAt(i)-48)*(big.charAt(j)-48)*product;

    }

    if(product>newProduct)
    {
        newProduct=product;

    }
}


    System.out.println(newProduct);
}
```

Comment: My name is "Integer overflow", how can I confuse you today?

Comment: Hi Integer overflow. It would be great if you could show me why you're confusing me :D

Comment: I confuse you, because you may think that I can hold the value `23514624000`, but the largest value I can hold is `2147483647`. How about meeting by big brother `long`, which can hold the maximum value of `9223372036854775807`, so `23514624000` wouldn't be any problem. (but this doesn't solve problems with your algorithm)

Answer (score 3):

You are experiencing integer overflow (use a `long`). `Character.digit(char,int)` (where the second argument is the radix) can get you the `int` value of a `char`). Also, you can use `Math.max(long, long)` to get the maximum of two `long`(s). Putting that together, it might look something like

```
long max = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < big.length() - 13; i++) {
    String str = big.substring(i, i + 13);
    long product = 1;
    for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
        product *= Character.digit(ch, 10);
    }
    max = Math.max(max, product);
}
System.out.println(max);
```

And I get (the *expected*)

```
23514624000
```

Comment: Your answer already provides working code, but if you like to explain to OP where his algo is wrong: `product=(big.charAt(i)-48)*(big.charAt(j)-48)*product;` this multiplies `(big.charAt(i)-48)` with "other numbers", which is wrong. It should be only `product=(big.charAt(j)-48)*product;` (or `product *= (big.charAt(j)-48)`).